# Using PHP variable in dns_get_record?

Tags: php

I'm getting an error with this code:

```
$type = "DNS_" . strtoupper($_GET['type']);
$array = dns_get_record($domain, $type);
```

Helpful info:

```
$_GET['type'] = "a"
```

If I enter `DNS_A` in `dns_get_record`, the code works.  But when entering `$type`, I get an error.

The type is dynamic and I get it from a URL parameter, which is why I can't hard code it in.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What "error" do you get?

Comment: @talha2k It doesn't show any error message with `E_ALL`.  Same as if you enter an invalid DNS type like `DNS_XXXXX`.

Comment: Do you have error reporting turned on? Add [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/) to the
top of your file(s) _while testing_ right after your opening PHP tag for example. 
Even if you are developing on a server configured as LIVE you will now see any errors. 
`<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: `DNS_A` is a pre defined integer not a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameter 2 has to be one of these predefined constants

```
DNS_A, DNS_CNAME, DNS_HINFO, DNS_CAA, DNS_MX, DNS_NS, DNS_PTR, DNS_SOA,
DNS_TXT, DNS_AAAA, DNS_SRV, DNS_NAPTR, DNS_A6, DNS_ALL or DNS_ANY
```

so you will need to get the value of the constant in order to make your code flexible like that.

You were passing a string so use `constant()` to convert that string into the integer value associated with that constant

Example

```
$_GET['type'] = 'a';

$type = constant("DNS_" . strtoupper($_GET['type']));
$domain = 'www.php.net';

$result = dns_get_record($domain, $type);
print_r($result);
```

RESULT

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [host] => www-php-net.ax4z.com
            [class] => IN
            [ttl] => 283
            [type] => A
            [ip] => 185.85.0.29
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

DNS_A actually means integer 1, NOT a string "DNS_A"

So please use

```
<?php
$type=1; 
$result = dns_get_record("php.net", $type );
print_r($result);
?>
```

or use $_GET['type'] = 1 and then use

```
<?php
$type=$_GET["type"]; 
$result = dns_get_record("php.net", $type );
print_r($result);
?>
```

Please see official documentation: ( int $type = DNS_ANY .... and so on)

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dns-get-record.php

Note: you can mix the $type like:

```
<?php
$dnsr = dns_get_record('php.net', DNS_A + DNS_NS);
// same as $dnsr = dns_get_record('php.net', 3);
print_r($dnsr);
?>
```

Keys (pre-defined constants)

```
DNS_A = 1
DNS_NS = 2
DNS_CNAME = 16
DNS_SOA = 32
DNS_PTR = 2048
DNS_HINFO = 4096
DNS_MX = 16384
DNS_TXT = 32768
DNS_A6 = 16777216
DNS_SRV = 33554432
DNS_NAPTR = 67108864
DNS_AAAA = 134217728
DNS_ALL = 251713587
DNS_ANY = 268435456
```

As advised by @bilbodog, there is also DNS_CAA:

```
DNS_CAA = 8192
```

Comment: I will just add one more record to your list: DNS_CAA = 8192

Comment: @bilbodog,  Thank you for your help ! (I have amended my answer to incorporate DNS_CAA)

Comment: Anytime, that is how we get better. Sharing is caring.

Answer (score 0):

dns_get_record expects second parameter to be Integer. In yoru case it is a string.

Please replace following numbers based on your required records:

```
$dns_record = dns_get_record('domain', REPLACE_RECORD_ID);
var_dump($dns_record);


DNS_A = 1
DNS_NS = 2
DNS_CNAME = 16
DNS_SOA = 32
DNS_PTR = 2048
DNS_HINFO = 4096
DNS_MX = 16384
DNS_TXT = 32768
```

[List of DNS Record Types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DNS_record_types)